# Promise { <pending> } in node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am trying to select items from sql server but I am getting below error. My SELECT statement right after completion on INSERT statement. What should I do to select properly without this error? Should I create separation connection?

> Promise {  }

**node.js**

```
//Receive from Angular Server 
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
var sql = require('mssql');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  next();
});

app.listen(1433, function (err) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    console.log('Example app listening on port 1433!')
})

var config = {
};

app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.send(res.body);
  var jsondata = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  var data = JSON.parse(jsondata);


  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log("Connection successful");

    var request = new sql.Request();

    request.input
      .input('Loc', data.Location).input('ara', data.area)
      .query('INSERT INTO Local_RMS (Location, Shift, PlanWld, ActualWld, OrWld, PlanPnt, ActualPnt, OrPnt, PlanAssy, OrAssy) VALUES (@Loc, @ara', (err, result) => {
        if (err)
          console.log(err);
        else
          console.log("Rows Affected : " + request.rowsAffected);
      })

      const result = request.query `SELECT * FROM Local_RMS WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN  '11-24-2017 11:17:00' and '11-24-2017 11:18:59'`;
      console.log(result); //error "Promise { <pending> }"
  })
});
```

Comment: Its not an error, you need to wait for the Promise to either `resolve` or `reject`. Change last line to `result.then(console.log).catch(console.error)`

Comment: thanks.. but I am not getting the concept of Promise, what is it exactly?

Comment: You can learn basic detail of promise from [this link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies)

Comment: Its difficult to explain in comments, https://davidwalsh.name/promises article might help. I couldn't find something that explains from scratch in a better way. We can start a chat thread if you still need help understanding it.

Comment: @AkshendraPratap - Why don't you write your comment into an answer?  You can also include a few references for learning promises in your answer.  Also may point to the sql-server page documentation on `request.query()` that shows some examples.  If not, someone else should provide that as an answer.

Comment: I didn't because the question is not asking not about how promises work. But I understand your point.